# Groovy equivalent of Ruby String#split

Tags: ruby, groovy

how to done this (Ruby) in Groovy:

`'foo bar'.split(' ' )`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`'foo bar'.split()`

For further info, check `String` class in [Groovy JDK](http://groovy.codehaus.org/groovy-jdk/).

Comment: This is not the same. It is the equivalent to Ruby `'foo bar'.split` without parameters, which splits on any whitespace. The Groovy `split()` does not allow you to split only on the space character. The exact equivalent would be `'foo bar'.tokenize(' ')`

Answer (score 2):

Even better than using `split()` is to use the Groovy `tokenize()` which will return a List instead of an Array of Strings. The no-arg version defaults to tokenizing on whitespace or you can pass it a delimiter.

```
groovy:000> 'foo bar'.tokenize()
===> [foo, bar]
groovy:000>
```

Comment: Add the `' '` parameter and it will be the same.

Answer (score 1):

It's also good to keep in mind that `tokenize()` will get rid of any empty strings:

```
groovy> println ",,a,,".tokenize(",")
===> [a]
```

while `split()` will only get rid of the trailing empty strings:

```
groovy> println ",,a,,".split(",") 
===> [, , a]

groovy> println "a,,,,".split(",")
===> [a]

groovy> println ",,,,".split(",")
===> []
```